# How to use log4j in Weblogic server

Tags: logging, log4j, weblogic-10.x

I use Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6, WL 10.3 on Win7. JDK 1.6.0.3x64
I tried to configure for 1 day during according to guides and informations on net. But i can not make it works unfortunately. Just after i start wls, encountered this:

```
<14-12-2012 10:42:00 o'clock EET> <Error> <Log Management> <BEA-170022> <Log4j failed to initialize for DefaultServer. The default JDK Logging implementation will be used.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.logging.log4j.JDKLog4jAdapterFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I followed up basically through those links https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1061248 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/logging/config_logs.html#using_log4j

I changed Logging implementation as Log4j from JDK: http://www.2hotfile.com/image.php?di=72YU

I created log4j.xml file under my %DOMAINHOME%\config : http://www.2hotfile.com/image.php?di=JHLI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd"> 
<log4j:configuration> 
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
<param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern"
value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender> 
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="/log/daily.log"/> 
<param name="Append" value="false"/>
<!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>
<logger name="org.apache">
<level value="WARN"/>
</logger>
<root>
<level value="DEBUG"/>
<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
<!-- <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> -->
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

i copied log4j.jar, wllog.jar into my %DOMAINHOME%\lib : http://www.2hotfile.com/image.php?di=BYB3
Even i copied commons-logging-1.0.4.jar and com.bea.core.weblogic.commons.logging_1.4.0.0.jar files into the lib folder and then i set CLASSPATH accordingly, result was negative.

I added these lines into startWeblogic.cmd

```
@REM customized here for log4j
set LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE=%DOMAIN_HOME%\config\log4j.xml
set SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.log.Log4jLoggingEnabled=true -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=%LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE%

set SAVE_CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%DOMAIN_HOME%\config;
```

Additionally i have tried adding log4j.jar into sysyem classpath becuse of classloading problem suspicion: http://www.2hotfile.com/image.php?di=7Y3N after view this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/479763/BEA-Weblogic/Log-Weblogic-ClassNotFoundException
What might be the reason of problem, help me plz

18.12.2012

I resolved the exception; Jdeveloper 11.1.1.4 was setted up on my pc as well. That was the cause of problem. System was looking some paths on 11.1.1.4 server folders that belong to 11.1.14 version.
Now, created server log which i defined in log4j.xml but *no log line found* in file, nothing logged according to log4j.xml config file and wls still writes its own log into its own log file which is under $domain_home$\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log. What might be the reason?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
                     debug="true">
 <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
 <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="./server.log"/>
  <param name="Append" value="false"/>
  <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
   <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
          -->
  </layout>
 </appender>
 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
 </appender>
 <category name="org.apache">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
 </category>
 <category name="com.weblogic">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
 </category>
 <category name="com.roketsan">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
 </category>
 <category name="org.hibernate">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
 </category>
 <category name="log4j.category.org.hibernate">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
 </category>
 <category name="log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL">
  <priority value="STDOUT"/>
 </category>
 <root>
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

*jdeveloper integrated weblogic console output:*  http://www.2hotfile.com/image.php?di=TPY2

```
*** Using port 7101 ***
C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
this is suuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuun
'LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE' i‡ ya da dis komut, ‡alistirilabilir
program ya da toplu is dosyasi olarak taninmiyor.
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\wcps-lib\derby-10.6.1.0.jar;C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\wcps-lib\derbytools-10.6.1.0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware_11.1.1.6\jdeveloper\webcenter\modules\oracle.portlet.server_11.1.1\oracle-portlet-api.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware_11.1.1.6\jdeveloper\webcenter\modules\wcps_11.1.1.6.0\wcps-connection-mbeans.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar;.
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6X64;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6X64\bin;C:\Oracle\database\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Oracle\database\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Users\Dijitaluser\Desktop\Yeni klas”r\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=52130 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\Middleware_11.1.1.6\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1 -Djrockit.optfile=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\servers\DefaultServer\tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -Dwsm.repository.path=C:\Users\DIJITA~1\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\oracle\store\gmds  -DUSE_JAAS=false -Djps.policystore.hybrid.mode=false -Djps.combiner.optimize.lazyeval=true -Djps.combiner.optimize=true -Djps.auth=ACC -Doracle.core.ojdl.logging.usercontextprovider=oracle.core.ojdl.logging.impl.UserContextImpl -noverify -Doracle.webcenter.analytics.disable-native-partitioning=false -Doracle.webcenter.tagging.scopeTags=false -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dportlet.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware_11.1.1.6\jdeveloper -Dwc.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware_11.1.1.6\jdeveloper  -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath -Dlog4j.ignoreTCL=true -Dweblogic.log.Log4jLoggingEnabled=true -Dlog4j.debug   weblogic.Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 52130
Debugger connected to local process.
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:09 o'clock EET> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:10 o'clock EET> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:10 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <Following extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath:
C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\lib\com.bea.core.weblogic.commons.logging_1.4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\lib\mbeantypes\csp-id-asserter.jar;C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\lib\mbeantypes\jps-wls-trustprovider.jar;C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\lib\wllog4j.jar> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:10 o'clock EET> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 20.5-b03 from Sun Microsystems Inc.> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:11 o'clock EET> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.5.0  Fri Apr 1 20:20:06 PDT 2011 1398638 > 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:12 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:12 o'clock EET> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:12 o'clock EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:12 o'clock EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log00016. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:12 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Log Management> <WL-170019> <The server log file C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader java.net.URLClassLoader@7df44ec7.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/Users/Dijitaluser/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system11.1.1.6.38.61.92/DefaultDomain/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory
log4j: debug attribute= "true".
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.apache] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.apache is  [DEBUG].
log4j: org.apache level set to DEBUG
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.weblogic] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.weblogic is  [DEBUG].
log4j: com.weblogic level set to DEBUG
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.roketsan] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.roketsan is  [DEBUG].
log4j: com.roketsan level set to DEBUG
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.hibernate] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.hibernate is  [DEBUG].
log4j: org.hibernate level set to DEBUG
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [log4j.category.org.hibernate] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for log4j.category.org.hibernate is  [DEBUG].
log4j: log4j.category.org.hibernate level set to DEBUG
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL is  [STDOUT].
log4j: log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [CONSOLE] to category [root].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [./server.log].
log4j: Setting property [append] to [false].
log4j: Setting property [datePattern] to ['.'yyyy-MM-dd].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d %-5p [%c] %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: ./server.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Appender [FILE] to be rolled at midnight.
log4j: Adding appender named [FILE] to category [root].
<18-12-2012 13:58:12 o'clock EET> <Warning> <NodeManager> <WL-300043> <Node manager native library not found - server process id not saved.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:13 o'clock EET> <Error> <Socket> <WL-000438> <Unable to load performance pack. Using Java I/O instead. Please ensure that wlntio.dll is in: 'C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6X64;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6X64\bin;C:\Oracle\database\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Oracle\database\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Users\Dijitaluser\Desktop\Yeni klasör\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.6\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8;.'
> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:19 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:20 o'clock EET> <Warning> <Store> <WL-280101> <The persistent file store "_WLS_DefaultServer" is forced to use buffered I/O and so may have significantly degraded performance. Either the OS/hardware environment does not support the chosen write policy or the native wlfileio library is missing. See store open log messages for the requested and final write policies. See the documentation on store synchronous write policy configuration for advice.> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:20 o'clock EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\access.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:20 o'clock EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\access.log00001. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\access.log.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:23 o'clock EET> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 0: oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.DomainLogHandler ERROR: unable to find instance of weblogic.logging.DomainLogBroadcastHandler> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:25 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <WL-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:25 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <WL-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:29 o'clock EET> <Warning> <J2EE> <WL-160195> <The application version lifecycle event listener oracle.security.jps.wls.listeners.JpsAppVersionLifecycleListener is ignored because the application Roketsan is not versioned.> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:37 o'clock EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultDomain.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<18-Dec-2012 13:58:37 o'clock EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultDomain.log00016. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Users\Dijitaluser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultDomain.log.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:37 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Log Management> <WL-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:37 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <WL-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:37 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <WL-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[11]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Warning> <Server> <WL-002611> <Hostname "AD190", maps to multiple IP addresses: 169.254.50.94, 192.168.26.212, fe80:0:0:0:a1be:61f:f156:325e%38> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:a1be:61f:f156:325e:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[10]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:a9fe:325e:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[7]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:a0d0:352d:6b23:d7dc:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[8]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:648c:26dc:32a5:1300:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:1ad4:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:34a0:7762:7e2f:fca8:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[9]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 192.168.26.212:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on 169.254.50.94:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <Server> <WL-002613> <Channel "Default[6]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:fdaf:7651:30df:acb6:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <WL-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "DefaultServer" for domain "DefaultDomain" running in Development Mode> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <WL-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING> 
<18-12-2012 13:58:38 o'clock EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <WL-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode> 
IntegratedWebLogicServer startup time: 30110 ms.
IntegratedWebLogicServer started.
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to log output of weblogic itself or just from your application? If you just want logging from your application you need not to put Log4j into the domain. Just put the *log4j.jar* in your application's lib folder ('WEB-INF/lib' ot 'APP-INF/lib') and your 'log4j.properties' in the application class path ('WEB-INF/classes' or 'APP-INF/classes').

Comment: what if one wants to log output of weblogic itself?